# More efficient algorithm for matrix rearrangement (MatLab)

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matlab

Say I have the following matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0.1 & 2 \\ 0.1 & 4 \\ 0.1 & 6 \\ 0.2 & 3 \\ 0.2 & 2 \\ 0.2 & 7 \\ 0.3 & 10 \\ 0.3 & 7 \\ 0.3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

I want this matrix rearranged so that all values in the second column belonging to one specific value in the first column becomes a new row (with the lowest number in the first column becoming the top row). Further, I want the numbers in the left column to become one array containing each number in increasing order.  So in this case I want to obtain the following matrix:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 6 \\ 3 & 2 & 7 \\ 10 & 7 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

and the vector:

$$\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 \end{bmatrix}$$

I have written a script in MatLab which works fine to accomplish this, but it requires some for-loops which I would rather avoid as the dataset I will be working on will have more than 100000 rows.  My code is as follows:

```
clear all
A = [.1 2; .1 4; .1 6; .2 3; .2 2; .2 7; .3 10; .3 7; .3 5];
B = size(A);
rown = B(1);
numb = 1;
xs = zeros(1,1);
xs(1)=A(1,1);
for i=1:(rown-1)
    if A(i+1,1) - A(i,1) > 0
        numb = numb + 1;
        xs(numb) = A(i+1,1);
    end
end

col = rown/numb;
B = zeros(numb,col);
m = col;
counter = 1;

for i=1:numb
    B(i,:) = A(counter:m,2)';
    counter = counter + col;
    m = m+col;
end
```

However, if anyone has some tips as to how I can achieve this without using loops, then I would be very grateful!

(PS: I am unsure as to whether or not this question belongs here or on stackoverflow, bus as Stackoverflow does not accept Latex, I decided to post the question here as I think it is important that I illustrate clearly the problem).

Comment: what if there are, for example, 4 elements for $0.1$, 3 elements for $0.2$ and 3 elements for $0.3$? How large will be $B$?

Comment: Hi.  With the dataset I will be working on, there will always be the same number of elements for each value in the left column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use reshape:

```
B=reshape(A(:,2),3,3)
```

For the second part, it depends on the structure of the first column, but for this specific case you can use the "unique()" function:

```
x=unique(A(:,1))'
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!  I had no idea it was this easy.  I really appreciate it :)